# Flake8Lint ERROR: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'kind'

Tags: python, python-3.x, sublimetext3, attributeerror, flake8

Started up Sublime Text 3 today and noticed Flake8Lint wasn't active.  I checked the console and had this long error:

```
Flake8Lint ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):
Flake8Lint ERROR: File "/Users/juliansmithdeniro/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/Python Flake8 Lint/lint.py", line 405, in 
Flake8Lint ERROR: for lint_warning in lint(stdin_lines, lint_settings):
Flake8Lint ERROR: File "/Users/juliansmithdeniro/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/Python Flake8 Lint/lint.py", line 206, in lint
Flake8Lint ERROR: for error in PEP257Checker().check_source(lines, ''):
Flake8Lint ERROR: File "/Users/juliansmithdeniro/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/Python Flake8 Lint/contrib/pydocstyle.py", line 1359, in check_source
Flake8Lint ERROR: module = parse(StringIO(source), filename)
Flake8Lint ERROR: File "/Users/juliansmithdeniro/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/Python Flake8 Lint/contrib/pydocstyle.py", line 275, in __call__
Flake8Lint ERROR: return self.parse_module()
Flake8Lint ERROR: File "/Users/juliansmithdeniro/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/Python Flake8 Lint/contrib/pydocstyle.py", line 428, in parse_module
Flake8Lint ERROR: children = list(self.parse_definitions(Module, all=True))
Flake8Lint ERROR: File "/Users/juliansmithdeniro/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/Python Flake8 Lint/contrib/pydocstyle.py", line 366, in parse_definitions
Flake8Lint ERROR: yield self.parse_definition(class_._nest(self.current.value))
Flake8Lint ERROR: File "/Users/juliansmithdeniro/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/Python Flake8 Lint/contrib/pydocstyle.py", line 485, in parse_definition
Flake8Lint ERROR: class_.__name__, name, self.current.kind,
Flake8Lint ERROR: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'kind'
```

I tried disabling and re-enabling, then uninstalling and reinstalling. If anyone has some knowledge they could pass on would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I got it.  Just replaced

`../Sublime Text 3/Packages/Python Flake8 Lint/contrib/pyflakes/checker.py`

with:
https://github.com/richardasaurus/Flake8Lint/blob/master/contrib/pyflakes/checker.py

Courtesy of this issue posted on GitHub: https://github.com/dreadatour/Flake8Lint/issues/61